# MarshalByRefType

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying example [from this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.aspx#Y8558), but get the error:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'MarshalByRefType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  C:\Dropbox\development\snipplets-examples\dot.net\appdomain\MyAppDomain\MyAppDomain\Program.cs  34  13  MyAppDomain
```

Code:

```
// Create an instance of MarshalbyRefType in the second AppDomain. 
// A proxy to the object is returned.
MarshalByRefType mbrt = 
            (MarshalByRefType) ad2.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                exeAssembly, 
                typeof(MarshalByRefType).FullName
            );
```

Comment: Should this just be `MarshalByRefObject` ? or is your `MarshalByRefType` a type that you have defined that `: MarshalByRefObject` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of the MarshalByRefType class is given in the page you've linked.